# Accessing the same mongoDB instance from multiple Docker containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, containers

I have two containers (A and B) running Node + MongoDB. `A` contains restricted endpoints that require a valid token in order to read + write from the database. `B` will contain public endpoints that have no request requirements and allow anyone to read certain documents from the database.

*The endpoints exposed in both `A` and `B` should interact with the same database*. I'm not sure how to do this when it comes to MongoDB.

I'm defining the schema / model for the collection in container `A`, like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Project = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
```

From container `B`, all I want to do is to be able to sift through all Projects in the database. I don't think I'm supposed to create the same schema in this new container.

It's important to note that **container B is successfully connected to the same DB as container A**. It's just a matter of sifting through it via mongoose.

**TL;DR**: How can I access container A's db from container B, where I haven't registered any models? I'm pretty new to this so any info would be helpful.

Comment: you probably should run mongo in another container and link (using `--link` )both node containers to it, that would be much cleaner solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `docker-compose.yml` like

```
mongodb:
 image: mongo
dockera:
 links:
   - mongodb:mongodb
dockerb:
 links:
   - mongodb:mongodb
```

then you containera and containerb will connect the same mongodb